# MySQL - MIN / MAX

Tags: mysql

I have a field in my database which can contain either a number e.g. 8.00 or range number e.g. 8.00 - 10.00.

I need to get the MIN() and the MAX() from the table if you take each number as a separate number. e.g. when a range is 8.00 - 10.00 the MIN is 8.00 and the MAX is 10.00

Example:

```
PRICE: 2.00-4.00
PRICE: 2.00-10.00
PRICE: 3.00
PRICE: 8.00

MIN = 2.00
MAX = 10.00
```

Can any one help?

Thanks

Comment: please add some sample data and expected resultset

Comment: should that MAX be 10.00?

Comment: Sorry yes it should!

Comment: What is the data type of that field? Is it a `varchar` as I suspect?

Comment: Apart from the question itself, a small modelization update seems useful.

Comment: Yes varchar. Yes eventually the database will be updated.

Comment: No, you're updating your database before solving this problem, because right now it's completely broken. Trying to do intelligent numeric queries on text data is a hopeless endeavour, and will be unreliable and buggy at best even if you succeed. Fix your database to be at least in the first normal form, then try to tackle this issue again.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes amazingly helpful, not!

Comment: It's likely the most helpful comment you could ever get - following my advice is going to save you hours if not days of future frustration. Your data model is broken, completely, if you need queries like this. If you fix it today, you can start writing actual code. If you don't, you'll be coding workaround hacks like this for the rest of the project, and take twice as long.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes you have no idea on the project, the background or the future of the project so how can you possibly comment? This is a place to help people with their problems not being a complete arse. If you don't want to contribute to solving the actual problem go and find another question to answer.

Comment: Does it matter? I don't need to know about the rest of the project to spot, like any experienced database architect, that this data model is broken. Don't call me an arse for pointing out stuff you don't want to hear, you came here for expert opinions: you're getting them. Be thankful.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I am not asking for advice on database architecture. Perhaps try reading the question before answering.

Comment: I read the question, and [spotted the glaring XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your question is only masking the *real* problem. Again, be thankful that someone is taking time, for free, to point that out, instead of ignoring it and giving you a broken query which will help you for a day and cause more issues further up ahead.

I daresay the asker who starts cursing at free advice is usually a bigger arse than the professional helping with a *fundamental* solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring_index` and `union`

```
select min(col),
max(col) 
from (
select 
substring_index(PRICE,'-',1) * 1 col
 from Table1
union 
select 
substring_index(PRICE,'-',-1) * 1 col2
from Table1
  ) t
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6337/4)

Comment: God just ate a kitten when this answer was posted. The fact that it is *possible* despite the completely broken data model, with a hopelessly unreliable and bad query, doesn't mean you should encourage TS continuing on his stray path.

Answer (score 0):

You should [normalize your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to 3NF or BCNF in order to avoid further problems. But if you're just curious about what's in your database you may try this query:

Query

```
SELECT
  MIN(TRIM(CASE WHEN INSTR(val, "-") > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(val, 1, INSTR(val, "-")-1) ELSE val END)) min,
  MAX(TRIM(CASE WHEN INSTR(val, "-") > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(val,    INSTR(val, "-")+1) ELSE val END)) max
FROM test;
```

Example output

```
+-------+-------+
| min   | max   |
+-------+-------+
| 1.00  | 30.00 |
+-------+-------+
```